# Automatic website screenshots for Web app?

Tags: web-applications, webpage-screenshot

Is there a way to take automatic screenshots of a web page (by specifying its URL) in a web app using PHP or Ruby on Rails? Perhaps using a plugin or some external REST service.

I've researched a lot, and nothing seems to fit except something like this (http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/02/automated-take-screenshots-website-free/) but I doubt Wordpress would just let me spam their servers for something not Wordpress related.

I'd like to use it for my own web application so I'm not sure of the legal implications..how hard is this to implement myself? What does it entail?

Thanks!

Comment: Also see http://browsershots.org/

Comment: I'm not looking to check browser compatibility, I want an easy way of returning images by URL without having to scrape a website like BrowserShots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will be what you are looking for: http://www.webshotspro.com/ (it's not free but quite cheap)

Comment: I've read about this, but there seems to be a long queue/waiting time  :\. Thanks, though!

Comment: this is time consuming by it's nature. basically to do this you need to launch some webbrowser and generate printscreen (as far as I know).